# Centos 7 increase telnet connection limit above 64

Tags: centos7, telnet, systemd

Telnet connections are getting refused after 64, system wide.

This message is filling up /var/log/messages.

`systemd: telnet.socket: Too many incoming connections (64)`

How do I increase it from the default 64?

Answer (score 0):

Set the new limit in the telnet.socket file.

Add the line: MaxConnections=2048 under [Socket].

**/lib/systemd/system/telnet.socket**

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=23
Accept=true
MaxConnections=2048
```

Restart the telnet daemon with:

**systemctl daemon-reload**